# Why has my nav element 100% width?

Tags: html, css, nav

This is my nav:

```css
    a{
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}
nav{
display:inline;
margin:auto;
margin-bottom:0;
padding:0;
background-color:white;
border: 1px solid white;
border-radius:12px;
}
nav > ul{
list-style-type:none;
display:inline;
}
nav > ul > li{
display:inline;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 200;
border:2px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 2px solid #078930;
margin-right:2%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <img src='http://www.gymnasium-allermoehe.de/Bilder/Frankreich/Flagge.jpg' style='width:75px;height:50px;border-radius:12px 0px 0px 12px;'>
            <ul>
               <li class='info'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/index.html'>Info</a></li>
               <li class='nature'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/nature.html'>Nature</a></li>
               <li class='cayenne'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/cayenne.html'>Cayenne</a></li>
               <li class='kourou'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/kourou.html'>Kourou</a></li>
            </ul>
 <img src='http://paradiseintheworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/french-guiana-flag.png' style='width:75px;height:50px;border-radius:0px 12px 12px 0px;'>
    </nav>
```

<del>The problem is that the nav has always 100% width of it's parent tag.
I cant specify a width, because I work with percent and images.
So what can I do that the nav takes only the space it needs?</del>
The ul is has a lower height than the images.

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the display property of the nav, just like you did with the ul? By the way, your `font-size` is missing a unit.

Comment: simply because this the default behavior of block element and nav is block element

Comment: Ok it solved the width problem but now the ul has a lower height than the images. I tried to make the css height the same as the images, but it doesnt work.

Comment: @Manuxx Probably the descender issue. Can you edit the question with the code you now have?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in comments, I suppose you're trying to vertically align middle `img` and `ul` elments. If so, you should add `vertical-align: middle;` to those elements, like so:

```css
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}
nav{
display:inline;
margin:auto;
margin-bottom:0;
padding:0;
background-color:white;
border: 1px solid white;
border-radius:12px;
}
nav img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav > ul{
list-style-type:none;
display:inline;
vertical-align: middle;
}
nav > ul > li{
display:inline;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 200;
border:2px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 2px solid #078930;
margin-right:2%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <img src='http://www.gymnasium-allermoehe.de/Bilder/Frankreich/Flagge.jpg' style='width:75px;height:50px;border-radius:12px 0px 0px 12px;'>
            <ul>
               <li class='info'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/index.html'>Info</a></li>
               <li class='nature'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/nature.html'>Nature</a></li>
               <li class='cayenne'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/cayenne.html'>Cayenne</a></li>
               <li class='kourou'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/kourou.html'>Kourou</a></li>
            </ul>
 <img src='http://paradiseintheworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/french-guiana-flag.png' style='width:75px;height:50px;border-radius:0px 12px 12px 0px;'>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use Flexbox...use `inline-flex` for the `nav` and `flex` for the `ul`

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  background: #efefef;
}

nav>ul>li {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #078930;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src='http://www.gymnasium-allermoehe.de/Bilder/Frankreich/Flagge.jpg' style='width:75px;height:50px;border-radius:12px 0px 0px 12px;'>
  <ul>
    <li class='info'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/index.html'>Info</a></li>
    <li class='nature'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/nature.html'>Nature</a></li>
    <li class='cayenne'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/cayenne.html'>Cayenne</a></li>
    <li class='kourou'><a href='http://manuel03.bplaced.net/guyane/kourou.html'>Kourou</a></li>
  </ul>
  <img src='http://paradiseintheworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/french-guiana-flag.png' style='width:75px;height:50px;border-radius:0px 12px 12px 0px;'>
</nav>
```